# function to be used in python to remove particular text after phrase

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

I have an output like :

```
apple
100
banana
50
orange
12
grapes
133
```

I have to remove the entire text after orange
and represent the output only as

```
apple
100
banana
50
```

which function in python we need to use (and the way i have written the output is correct only it represent one by one order)?

Answer (score 1):

If the output has found ***orange*** then stop printing the output.

```
for some_statement:
    if text == "orange":
          break;
```

Comment: It must be of python coding not C coding and break cananot be used in if condition you must have iterations

Answer (score 1):

if the output is in stats

```
print stats.split("orange")[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Expressing output as `output`:

```
output = output.split("orange")
print output[0]
# or for Python 3, print(output[0]).
```

Keep in mind that when splitting by `"orange"`, the string `"orange"` will be removed from the array, so if your output string was `"apple orange potato"` then `output[0]` will be `apple`, then `output[1]` will be `potato`, so if you want to use `orange` later at all, then use a different method.